# abp.sweet-alert.js - No localization on buttons with v3.5.0

Tags: localization, aspnetboilerplate, sweetalert2

I have a project with ABP 3.5.0 ASP.NET Core and Angular, including Sweetalert 2.0.8.

When a delete button is pressed (ex. roles or tenants), confirm dialog doesn't localize the buttons Cancel and Yes. I have tried to get a fresh template today, same behavior.

I have tried to change abp.sweet-alert.js as expected here, but no luck:
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2708

Here you can see the fresh template for today. I have tried to get an Italian Translation of the confirm Buttons. As you can see on the menu, 'About' was translated.

[SEE HERE PICTURE from fresh template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Ktv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I fixed the issue!

Open **root.module.ts**  and add the below line into the  AppPreBootstrap.run() callback method.

> abp.event.trigger('abp.dynamicScriptsInitialized');

Final look of the **root.module.ts** is below

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule, Injector, APP_INITIALIZER, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

import { AbpModule, ABP_HTTP_PROVIDER } from '@abp/abp.module';

import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
import { ServiceProxyModule } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxy.module';
import { RootRoutingModule } from './root-routing.module';

import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';
import { AppSessionService } from '@shared/session/app-session.service';
import { API_BASE_URL } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';

import { RootComponent } from './root.component';
import { AppPreBootstrap } from './AppPreBootstrap';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';


export function appInitializerFactory(injector: Injector) {
    return () => {

        abp.ui.setBusy();
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            AppPreBootstrap.run(() => {
                abp.event.trigger('abp.dynamicScriptsInitialized');
                var appSessionService: AppSessionService = injector.get(AppSessionService);
                appSessionService.init().then(
                    (result) => {
                        abp.ui.clearBusy();
                        resolve(result);
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        abp.ui.clearBusy();
                        reject(err);
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    }
}

export function getRemoteServiceBaseUrl(): string {
    return AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl;
}

export function getCurrentLanguage(): string {
    return abp.localization.currentLanguage.name;
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        SharedModule.forRoot(),
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        AbpModule,
        ServiceProxyModule,
        RootRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        RootComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ABP_HTTP_PROVIDER,
        { provide: API_BASE_URL, useFactory: getRemoteServiceBaseUrl },
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
            deps: [Injector],
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useFactory: getCurrentLanguage
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class RootModule {

}
```

- Proof:

[image: Abp Angular SweetAlert Localization Fix]

- Issue for this:

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/issues/200

- Fix for this:

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/commit/8752cd1b4f33afc1c8330f9990f3a6395b14bfeb